# Live candlestick chart protractor test

Tags: testing, protractor, candlestick-chart

Has anyone tried to test live candlestick chart using protractor?
like in this sites: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/candlestick-chart/
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update/grid-light